# Web Player Scorm previewer?

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I'm very new to SCORM and i'm not entirely sure if i'm even asking this question correctly so please pardon my newness. I have been tasked with implementing a SCORM "previewer" functionality into a website we're building.

I won't need any of the extended features that i understand are provided by the SCORM wrapper such as LMS integration and testing, but simply the ability to preview the images and flash files as they were created by the author of the SCORM package.

We have additional requirements that prevent us from using an external cloud-based solution.

Is this possible? Am i completely misunderstanding the way this works?

Answer (score 1):

The SCORM specification defines a Content Aggregation Model (CAM) and RunTime Environment (RTE). The CAM isn't relevant to your question but the RTE might. The RTE defines how SCORM content communicates with an LMS.

It sounds like in your 'previewer' application, you don't want to store any data in the LMS. For some SCORM packages, this will mean there is no work to do at all as you don't need to implement anything to store no data!

Other SCORM packages will expect a response from the LMS and will error if they don't receive one. I suspect this is what is happening in your case and why you have been tasked with creating a previewer application. You will therefore need to work out which SCORM data the package is sending, catch those requests and return the expected response. See [scorm.com](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=runtime?pmc=em-1) for an [overview of the Run Time Environment](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=runtime?pmc=em-1).

If you need a more generic solution that will work with any SCORM package, I fear you will need a complete SCORM implementation. This will be a LOT of work to do yourself. I would normally recommend [SCORM Cloud](http://cloud.scorm.com?utm_source=cloud_scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm_cloud?pmc=em-1) but you say you need an internally hosted solution. If this preview application is likely to be well used and/or customer facing, you should take a look at [SCORM Engine](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm-engine?pmc=em-1). If not, perhaps consider hosting an Open Source LMS such as Moodle?